# Parse complex element XML in Java with DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

```
<message>
    <element1>
        <arrival point="string">
            <positionAndTime>
                <Time>
                    <estimated time="2017-10-14T10:43:00Z"/>
                </Time>
            </positionAndTime>
        </arrival>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <depart point="string">
            <positionAndTime>
                <Time>
                    <estimated time="2017-10-14T10:43:00Z"/>
                </Time>
            </positionAndTime>
        </depart>
    </element2>
</message>
```

This is a simplified version of my XML document. 
I am writing a JavaEE application, a but confused on parsing the XML. So far I have been able to iterate over it and receive the strings from arrival point=string and depart point=string, but I am having issue understanding how to get the "estimated time" blocks from elements 1 and 2. I could just simply getElementsByTagName but since they are named the same in elements1 and 2 and I need to keep them separate....

Comment: Have you tried JAXB; Just writing a class to map the XML and just access the properties like an object; https://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-tutorial

Comment: Looking through the link you supplied, I think this might be a more organized approach than DOM. However, my problem still remains. the two time stamps are named the same but organized differently under arrival and depart. According to the documentation, I cant find a way to tell which one is which in the code. Arrival time stamp will be sent to a SQL database as well as depart time stamp. How to tell one from the other when parsing with JAX or DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Simple !

For Differentiating you have take them in a Pojo class where you name them differently.

```
class MessageParser{

private String arrivalEstimatedTime;
private String departureEstimatedTime;
 .. 
 //getters and setters
 public String getArrivalEstimatedTime() {
    return arrivalEstimatedTime;
}

public void setArrivalEstimatedTime(String arrivalEstimatedTime) {
    this.arrivalEstimatedTime = arrivalEstimatedTime;
}

public String getDepartureEstimatedTime() {
    return departureEstimatedTime;
}

public void setDepartureEstimatedTime(String departureEstimatedTime) {
    this.departureEstimatedTime = departureEstimatedTime;
}
}
```

When you traverse the xml you know where your are (in arrival tag or departure tag)

So when you are inside the  `<arrival point="string">` tag set the value as below

```
MessagePojo message=new MessagePojo();

message.SetArrivalEstimatedTime(arrival_Time_From_XML);
```

Same goes for Estimated Departure Time.

Now you have the data(arrivalEstimatedTime,departureEstimatedTime) , you send the values as required